# How to enable downloads for EXE files on windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Our Windows 2008 R2 server provides downloads to requests for ZIP files but not for EXE files (resource not found), even though EXE is included in the mimetypes list for the server and the site.

There is little to no info about this returned from web search.

It is not URLSCAN that is the problem as this is set to allow EXE. What have I missed?

Comment: Choose proper tag to get answer/help.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if EXE are assigned to "CGIModule" or "StaticFileModule" in Handler Mappings. Usually CGIModule is turned off, and thus throws an error. Reassign EXE to "StaticFileModule".